# Conditional class member based on template

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to have a class that receives a mutex type as template parameter to be (conditionally) thread-safe. If the mutex type is equal to NoMutex(my mutex empty implementation), I don't want to add this mutex member to my class so I can save space.
I want to do something like this:

```cpp
class NoMutex{
// Same interface as std::mutex but empty implementation
// so optimization can remove unnecessary function calls
};

template <class Mutex>
class MyClass {
    public:
    // Actually I want to hide it somehow. I dont want it to occupy any space if Mutex == NoMutex
    some_template_trick<std::is_same_v<Mutex, NoMutex, void, Mutex> mutex;

    void someFunction(){
        std::unique_lock<Mutex> l(getMutex()); // I want to use std::unique_lock here
        // do some concurrent stuff

    }


    Mutex& getMutex(){
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Mutex, NoMutex>){
            //ok... return reference to temporary is wrong, but i'm hopping
            //that gcc will realize there is nothing to be done once all implementations
            //are empty.
            return NoMutex();
        }
        return mutex;
    }
};
```

I don't want to specialize the class nor create lock() unlock() methods, I want them to be managed by std::unique_lock();
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you still want to create a std::unique_lock when using NoMutex?

Comment: Because otherwise I have to duplicate the someFunction implementation inside if constexpr and inside else. I could write another function and call it inside if/else (each once). But what I really want to know is if it is possible to conditionally add a data member to a class, like it is possible to add a code that compiles only if some type is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty data members can be optimized away using *empty base-class optimization* (EBO). That is, although a stateless class has non-zero size (at least 1 byte), it doesn't consume additional memory if used as a base class:

```cpp
template <typename Mutex>
struct CompressedMutex
{
    Mutex mutex;
    Mutex& getMutex() { return mutex; }
};

template <>
struct CompressedMutex<NoMutex> : NoMutex
{
    NoMutex& getMutex() { return *this; }
};

template <typename Mutex>
class MyClass : CompressedMutex<Mutex>
{
public: 
    void someFunction()
    {
        std::unique_lock<Mutex> l(this->getMutex());
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3712a7d29764075)

Note that `this->` or `CompressedMutex<Mutex>::` is required when accessing `getMutex()` which is a dependent name.

---

Usually, however, one would want to lock a mutex also in `const`-qualified member functions. For that, the `mutable` keyword could be used in the definition of a mutex data member. In the `NoMutex` case that would instead require using `const_cast<CompressedMutex&>(*this)`, or declaring a `static` object that is returned instead:

```cpp
template <typename Mutex>
struct CompressedMutex
{
    mutable Mutex mutex;
    Mutex& getMutex() const { return mutex; }
};

template <>
struct CompressedMutex<NoMutex>
{
    static NoMutex mutex;
    NoMutex& getMutex() const { return mutex; }
};
```

---

This technique has been widely used in the standard library so that a stateless allocator (including `std::allocator<T>`) does not account for the total size of a container. Such objects are usually stored in a so called *compressed pair* (e.g., [`boost::compressed_pair`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/utility/doc/html/compressed_pair.html)) or its variation, sometimes together with a non-empty data member, so that the interface of an enclosing class does not change:

```cpp
#include <boost/compressed_pair.hpp>

template <typename Mutex>
class MyClass
{
public: 
    void someFunction()
    {
        std::unique_lock<Mutex> l(data.second());
    }
private:
    boost::compressed_pair<SomeDataMemberType, Mutex> data;
};
```

Comment: Perfect! Is mutable required?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a struct wrapper holding either one or two things (untested code):

```
template <class T1, class T2> class Pair {
   Pair (const T1 &t1, const T2 &t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {}
   T1 & first () { return t1_; }
   T2 & second () { return t2_; }

   T1 t1_;
   T2 t2_;
};

template <class T1> class Pair<T1, NoMutex> {
   Pair (const T1 &t1) : t1_(t1) {}
   T1 & first () { return t1_; }
   NoMutex second () { return NoMutex(); }

   T1 t1_;
};
```

Comment: But if I add this Pair class to MyClass it will always occupy at least one byte. How could it not occupy any byte?

Comment: @MasterID: You put some other member of your class as the other `Pair` parameter.